# Batch sparse matrix multiplication in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

Is there a way to perform batch sparse matrix multiplication in Tensorflow? These are the shapes I am trying to multiply:

[ n , m , i , j ] x [ n , m , j , k ] = [ n , m , i , k ]

So, there is a batch component in both sides, and each 2D inner matrix pair should be multiplied accordingly. Is there a way with the currently implemented functions?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't mention if you tried anything so I'll just post this now.

From the tensorflow documentation, [tf.matmul](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul) supports batched 
multiplication.

```
matmul(
a,
b,
transpose_a=False,
transpose_b=False,
adjoint_a=False,
adjoint_b=False,
a_is_sparse=False,
b_is_sparse=False,
name=None
)
```

Comment: This answer might be incorrect. The documentation says the optimization for sparse matrices works only for rand 2 tensors.